# config.h doesn't work after using make command

Tags: c, x-dwm

I just made a new fresh Arch install with DWM. The problem is: after customizing the `config.h` using `sudo nano config.h` and running `sudo make` command then `reboot` the keybinding that I have set doesn't work at all.

```
/* See LICENSE file for copyright and license details. */

/* appearance */
static const unsigned int borderpx  = 1;        /* border pixel of windows */
static const unsigned int snap      = 32;       /* snap pixel */
static const int showbar            = 1;        /* 0 means no bar */
static const int topbar             = 1;        /* 0 means bottom bar */
static const char *fonts[]          = { "monospace:size=10" };
static const char dmenufont[]       = "monospace:size=10";
static const char col_gray1[]       = "#334257";
static const char col_gray2[]       = "#476072";
static const char col_gray3[]       = "#548CA8";
static const char col_gray4[]       = "#112031";
static const char col_cyan[]        = "#79B4B7";
static const char *colors[][3]      = {
    /*               fg         bg         border   */
    [SchemeNorm] = { col_gray3, col_gray1, col_gray2 },
    [SchemeSel]  = { col_gray4, col_cyan,  col_cyan  },
};

/* tagging */
static const char *tags[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

static const Rule rules[] = {
    /* xprop(1):
     *  WM_CLASS(STRING) = instance, class
     *  WM_NAME(STRING) = title
     */
    /* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
    { "Gimp",     NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
    { "Firefox",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 8,       0,           -1 },
};

/* layout(s) */
static const float mfact     = 0.55; /* factor of master area size [0.05..0.95] */
static const int nmaster     = 1;    /* number of clients in master area */
static const int resizehints = 1;    /* 1 means respect size hints in tiled resizals */
static const int lockfullscreen = 1; /* 1 will force focus on the fullscreen window */

static const char *upvol[]   = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "0", "+5%",     NULL };
static const char *downvol[] = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "0", "-5%",     NULL };
static const char *mutevol[] = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-mute",   "0", "toggle",  NULL };
static const char *web[] = { "chromium", NULL };

static const Layout layouts[] = {
    /* symbol     arrange function */
    { "[]=",      tile },    /* first entry is default */
    { "><>",      NULL },    /* no layout function means floating behavior */
    { "[M]",      monocle },
};

/* key definitions */
#define MODKEY Mod1Mask
#define TAGKEYS(KEY,TAG) \
    { MODKEY,                       KEY,      view,           {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask,           KEY,      toggleview,     {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             KEY,      tag,            {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask, KEY,      toggletag,      {.ui = 1 << TAG} },

/* helper for spawning shell commands in the pre dwm-5.0 fashion */
#define SHCMD(cmd) { .v = (const char*[]){ "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, NULL } }

/* commands */
static char dmenumon[2] = "0"; /* component of dmenucmd, manipulated in spawn() */
static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-m", dmenumon, "-fn", dmenufont, "-nb", col_gray1, "-nf", col_gray3, "-sb", col_cyan, "-sf", col_gray4, NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "st", NULL };

static Key keys[] = {
        /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
        { MODKEY,                       XK_p,      spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_w,       spawn,          {.v = web }},
        { MODKEY,                       XK_b,      togglebar,      {0} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_j,      focusstack,     {.i = +1 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_k,      focusstack,     {.i = -1 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_h,      setmfact,       {.f = -0.05} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_l,      setmfact,       {.f = +0.05} },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, zoom,           {0} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_Tab,    view,           {0} },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_c,      killclient,     {0} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_t,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[0]} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_f,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[1]} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_m,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_space,  setlayout,      {0} },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_space,  togglefloating, {0} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_0,      view,           {.ui = ~0 } },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_0,      tag,            {.ui = ~0 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_comma,  focusmon,       {.i = -1 } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_period, focusmon,       {.i = +1 } },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_comma,  tagmon,         {.i = -1 } },
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_period, tagmon,         {.i = +1 } },
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_1,                      0)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_2,                      1)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_3,                      2)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_4,                      3)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_5,                      4)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_6,                      5)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_7,                      6)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_8,                      7)
        TAGKEYS(                        XK_9,                      8)
        { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_q,      quit,           {0} },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_F11, spawn, {.v = downvol } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_F9,  spawn, {.v = mutevol } },
        { MODKEY,                       XK_F12, spawn, {.v = upvol   } },
};


/* button definitions */
/* click can be ClkTagBar, ClkLtSymbol, ClkStatusText, ClkWinTitle, ClkClientWin, or ClkRootWin */
static Button buttons[] = {
    /* click                event mask      button          function        argument */
    { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button1,        setlayout,      {0} },
    { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button3,        setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
    { ClkWinTitle,          0,              Button2,        zoom,           {0} },
    { ClkStatusText,        0,              Button2,        spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button1,        movemouse,      {0} },
    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button2,        togglefloating, {0} },
    { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button3,        resizemouse,    {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button1,        view,           {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button3,        toggleview,     {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button1,        tag,            {0} },
    { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button3,        toggletag,      {0} },
};
```

Comment: Please include the customization you've made into the question.

Also, not sure if DWM should be built as root.

Comment: cant put the code here so uploaded it https://anonfiles.com/vf4cvaH8ua/config_h
also i cant save changes without root in nano :)

Comment: The changes look fine so it's probably something else. Can you run those commands successfully as a user? Have you actually installed what you've compiled (i.e. `make install`)? Does MODKEY+w open Chromium?

Comment: 1 MODKEY+w dosent open chromium
2 if u are talking about the commands in the question then only root is required to save changes of nano
3 no I've not installed what i compiled just make command only

Comment: `make install` is a necessary step to actually install the compiled package (including configuration) into the system: "The prescribed way to install dwm is to clone the official git repo, run `make`, and then `make install`" -- from the Arch wiki on DWM.

Comment: THANK YOU ! so make install was what the solution thx again

Answer (score 1):

So the solution as https://stackoverflow.com/users/577167/joulukuusi said is to make sure to do `make install`

Answer (score 0):

I think u must write the config.def.h, not config.h. When i recompile dwm i do:

```
rm config.h
make
sudo make install
```

And all of this in one